# Why do these collection objects only contain _id?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I have a number of Collections successfully publishing to the client, however one is being stubborn:

on the DB there is a Collection 'cargoes'. The collection contains two documents, and they have a number of fields.

```
// in /lib/collections/cargoes.js
Cargoes = new Meteor.Collection('cargoes');
```

on the server side we're publishing /server/server.js

```
Meteor.publish('cargoes', function() { return Cargoes.find(); } );
```

on the client side we're subscribed in /client/main.js

```
Meteor.subscribe('cargoes');
```

When I type in Cargoes.find().fetch(); in the browser's (client's) console, I get back two objects that only have the correct _id values of the objects I expect back, **but no other fields**.

Any ideas of what could be going wrong, or how to debug this?

EDIT1 - Fixed a typo in the code, the publish has always had the return, i missed it when I entered on StackOverflow.

Comment: I think you forgot to `return` in your publish function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your publish function isn't giving anything back

```
Meteor.publish('cargoes', function() {
    return Cargoes.find(); 
});
```

-- Update -- 
If this isnt working, double check that the objects are valid via the mongo shell. `meteor mongo` or `mrt mongo` . Ensure the object doesnt have a [field named "length"](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/594) . Ensure you can properly find().fetch() the objects on the server :

**in file /server/main.js:**

```
if ( Meteor.isServer ) {
  console.log(Cargoes.findOne());    
}
```

Comment: I just fixed my question. In my code I was properly returning. Good catch though.

Comment: If you check your database are the fields all there?

Comment: correct, the full json is in the mongodb ; db.cargoes.find().pretty();. In the browser console Cargoes.find().fetch(); is returning the correct _id values, but nothing else.

Comment: If you add back the `auto publish` package does it work? Do you have two publish functions by any chance?

Comment: It related to the data being corrupt in the mongodb, when I emptied out the collection and reentered test values, they came out properly. Somehow there were objects within the collection that meteor couldnt send up to the client (or only would send the _id at least). Our project has moved on so I cant spend anymore time looking into this.